# How can I include AutomationElement in c# ? What do I have to add?

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation

I can't initialize the AutomationElement.

```
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
```

It highlights the AutomationElement The error it says is https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNCvq.png

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the relevant assembly and add a using statement to use the class. In this case you need the `UIAutomationClient.dll` assembly and the using statement: `using System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement`at the top of your class.

For more info, visit the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: that was it, idk why he did not mark your answer as accepet?

Answer (score 7):

The `UIAutomationClient.dll` need to be referenced in the project. The DLL file is located at `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0`

Answer (score 3):

In the project explorer 
Add references : UIAutomationClient AND UIAutomationTypes