# VS2019 Community vb .net - type "AutomationElement" is not defined

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I added reference to UIAutomationTypes and to UIAutomationClient
and use those imports

```
    Imports System.Windows.Automation
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
    Imports System.Text
```

But I get an error:
**type "AutomationElement" is not defined**
when I use that code

```
 Dim rootElement As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd)
```

what is wrong?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469386/referencing-system-windows-automation may help if it is a problem from the Imports

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737003/how-can-i-include-automationelement-in-c-sharp-what-do-i-have-to-add. please refer this solutions.

Comment: I get an error when I add "using System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement"
AutomationElement is not a member of System.Windows.Automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK
I had to add reference "UIAutomationClient" from files and not to choose from reference manager

Answer (score 0):

After setting a reference to

- UIAutomationClient
- UIAutomationCore
- UIAutomationCoreRes

all in uiautomationcore.dll you can do things like this in vb .net

```
Imports System

Module Program

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim uiA As UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation8 = New UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation8
        Dim root As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement

        root = uiA.GetRootElement()

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + root.CurrentClassName)
    End Sub
End Module
```

to be complete example in c#

```
    using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation8 uia = new UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation8();
            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement root;

            root = uia.GetRootElement();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + root.CurrentClassName);
        }
    }
}
```